# ssh + ssh is stuck on remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, redhat

simple script in order to perform reboot on Linux machine

```
for i in $LIST_OF_LINUX_MACHINES
do
   ssh $LINUX_MACHINE /var/tmp/restart.sh
done
```

after running this script couple of times ,

some times the ssh process is stuck! ( and loop is stuck on current machine )-

so how it can be - what could be the reason that in rare case ssh is stuck

and how to avoid that?

Comment: It specifies the *TCP* connect timeout. It's not a total-amount-of-time-your-command-is-guaranteed-to-complete-in value; lots of other places other than establishing the connection at the TCP layer things can get hung up.

Comment: BTW, BashFAQ #68 may be of interest: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068

Comment: BTW (also), `$LIST_OF_LINUX_MACHINES` is a code smell for several reasons. One of those reasons is that you're using it as a list, but it *isn't* a list, it's a string (the proper way to store a list of items is as an array, but iterating over an array looks like `for host in "${linux_machines[@]}"; do`).  Another is that all-caps variable names are reserved for variables with meaning to the shell and operating system -- see relevant POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, 4th paragraph, keeping in mind that shell and env vars share a namespace.

Comment: Charles - can you help me to show me how to add my ssh syntax in process with &  "according to your article"

Comment: If I'm going to write a best-practices example, I'd also want to replace the way we're getting the list of hosts with something that conforms with said practices. Where are you getting your list of machines from? Is it a file, one host per?

Comment: It'd also be worth considering entirely alternate approaches, if available tools permit. Do you have an xargs release with `-P`? Do you have a `timeout` command?

Comment: I use awk to insert the list of machines from a file to the variable  LIST_OF_LINUX_MACHINES

Comment: And the output from `awk` is in what form? Line-oriented? Also, which precise version of bash is this (or, more to the point, is it before or after 4.0)?

Comment: I want to say that the final target is to use "while read line" loop in place  of the for loop

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. `readarray` or `mapfile` may be an appropriate tool, depending (on details not yet in evidence).

Comment: my bash version is - 3.2.25(1)-release

Comment: ...well, phooey; that rules out a lot of shiny new features. And what's the answer on whether you have `xargs -P`, again? `timeout`?

Comment: Charles - can you show me the full syntax that you want to change on my ssh line?

Comment: I don't know what I want to change **until you tell me what tools you have**, so I can come up with the best available alternative given the circumstances. I've already asked twice.

Comment: Charles - what you mean what tool I Have - what I need to check on my system to verify?

Comment: Does your `xargs` have a `-P` argument? If you run `man xargs`, is there a `-P`?

Comment: Do you have a `timeout` command? If you run `type timeout` or `which timeout`, does it give you a path to a command, or a not-found error?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not a programming question, but rather a Linux usage question. Please re-ask this question on Unix & Linux (http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest something rather different -- instead of having a fixed delay between instances, having a fixed maximum number of instances to run at a time. For instance, with that value at 25:

```
numprocs=25
timeout=5
xargs -P "$numprocs" -J '{}' -n 1 -- \
  perl -e 'alarm shift; exec @ARGV' -- "$timeout" \
    ssh -nxaq -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no '{}' /tmp/reboot.sh \
  <hostnames # if a file; use < <(awk ...) if a script providing per-line info
```

Note that `-J {}` is an extension which avoids bugs implicit in the specification for the (standards-mandated) `-I {}` xargs behavior. If it's not available, `-I '{}'` can be used instead -- but do read the man page to understand caveats.

Comment: just one question - why machine IP  not before  /tmp/reboot.sh ?

Comment: `{}` is replaced with the actual hostname by xargs when using `-J {}`. This can't be done by the shell because the shell only runs one subcommand -- `xargs` -- and it's that command responsible for starting all the individual perl processes, each of which invokes a single `ssh` process.

Comment: see my update in the question

Comment: ...so you have an ancient xargs. Fun. Try `-I {}` instead, then.

Comment: I try the script is hang ( not return prompt )

Comment: ...and if you look at the process tree, you have what going on? (To be clear, I didn't post this until I'd tested it, albeit of course with a command that didn't involve rebooting).

Comment: ...you might take the `-n` out and add a `-v` if you want more visibility, btw.

Comment: I get xargs: invalid option -- v

Comment: I meant take out the `-n` **ssh** argument, not the **xargs** one. The xargs argument is mandatory.

Comment: it seems that ssh inst activate ( so this is the reason that I not have output )

Comment: maybe we need to try other simple approach

Comment: "ssh inst activate"? What do these words mean in this order?

Comment: I add "-v" as ssh argument and I not see any output

Comment: I'd actually like to see a reproducer for the bug you're seeing before moving on.  Yes, you're on a system with much older tools than I'm testing with, but that only makes a difference up to a point, and we're past that point.

Comment: If you replace `ssh` with `printf '%s\n' ssh`, is the result enlightening?

Comment: Waitaminute -- rereading the code in the question: You left out the redirection. That redirection is **critical** -- without it, the script is just going to keep waiting for a list of hostnames on stdin and never run anything

Comment: please see my update from my question - now I get  /test: line 7: 192.2.3.22: No such file or directory

Comment: `<192.2.3.22` is trying to read a list of hostnames from a FILE named 192.2.3.22. Of course that won't work. It wants a filename. Give it a filename.

Comment: OK , what in case I not want to use file , - only to set hostname or IP ?

Comment: I already told you that in the answer. If you want to stream a list of names from awk, for instance, use `< <(awk ...)`.